# One page wordpress template with subscription option

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm new to wordpress. I have to create a one page template for my site and show a subscribe textbox on it with my own custom style. Later, I will use it to send monthly newsletters. What can be the simplest way to do that? I saw into some plugins like newsletter, subscribe2, but they are complicated and I don't know how to integrate them with my text box. They just provide some sort of widget to show on sidebar. Any tutorial or simple plugin? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three options:

a. Use a web-hosted syndication service as per the below. (Easiest to configure)

b. Install some sort of newsletter sending plugin for WordPress. (More control, but more configuration)

c. Use a web-hosted newsletter service like Constant Contact (Expensive and Ugh.).

Try using Feedburner with email subscriptions -- see: http://howtotechtips.blogspot.com/2008/05/create-feedburner-email-subscription.html. You sign up, supply your RSS feed's address, then copy-paste the resulting code where-ever in your template you like. Then, whenever you write a new post, your subscribers are sent an email.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe2 complicated?

You can do auto-download/install from the administration area, you literally only have to config a few options.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Installing_Plugins

Maybe it's just me, but the screenshots certainly make the plugin appear to be very straight-forward.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not heavy with subscription list. Then a good option can be using the MailChimp email subscription with its free option.

You can just install the plugin and place a function called `mailchimpSF_signup_form()` into your template's right place. And beautify it with your own CSS.

Or in Post or pages' HTML using the shortcode `[mailchimpsf_form]`

They also have widget to be added dynamically. How to use it?

1. Create a free account at MailChimp.
2. Create a list there.
3. Create an API key there
4. Go to your MailChimp options page http://yourwordpress.tld/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=mailchimpSF_options
5. Insert the API key there.
6. Select the list you want this subscription to be linked to.

There you are!